# 6 thyristor scr

Tags: thyristor

I have three thyristor and three diodes scr working inside welding machine and drived by good pcb (working very good ).
The problem is that I need to replace the three diode by thyristor to use all 6 thyrosters , but I have only three gates and one common cathode to the three thyristor.
What can I do to make it 6 gate signals and isolated cathode signals?

Thanks for your time and only as note that the pcb I am using based on 555 timer ic

Answer (score 0):

That is a pretty extensive redesign. You will need to add isolation, probably pulse-transformers for each gate drive. You also need to change the gate pulse pattern.

Comment: Thanks for replying,  if you have any video or internal post please forward